# Authentication error "bad credentials" only in docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have standart formlogin and it works, my app saves user data into db in register page and checks data and authenticate user in login page. But when I use docker I get "Bad credentials" error in login page even if I wrote proper login and password. Here's my code:

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=<password>

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.trace.http.include=RESPONSE_HEADERS, PRINCIPAL
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=<password>
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=create
      - spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
      - spring.jpa.database=postgresql
      - spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    volumes:
            - sample_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password>
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
  sample_db: {}
```

controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/register")
public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "signup";
}

@PostMapping("/process_register")
public String processRegister(User user) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "register_success";
}
```

template:

```
<form th:action="@{/process_register}" th:object="${user}"
            method="post" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="m-3">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4 col-form-label">E-mail: </label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" required />
                </div>
            </div>
             
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Password: </label>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control"
                            required minlength="6" maxlength="10"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
     
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;
     
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String password;

    User() {}

    public User(Long id, String email, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a new user after dockerizing?

Comment: @Zamir My registration page and registration form works, its redirect me to another page with success message, but probably it only seems like works and data not saved in db. Idk how to check postgresql data in docker container, I tried several solutions for that but its doesnt worked for me

Comment: @Zamir I just asked another person to test my app and he said that my login system worked properly on his computer. So this problem relevant only to me

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. i just made git push with .gitignore, clone this repo, run "./mvnw clean package", delete docker container, images and then run "docker-compose up"